# Electron: details.webContentsId dissapears in release (session.webRequest.onBeforeRequest event)

Tags: electron, release, development-environment, web-content

I am working in an [Electron](https://electronjs.org) project in where I have several [webviews](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) to load different websites that share the same session (of the type “persist:id”). I have developed an adblock system that works at the level of the webview that works in the following way:

```
let mySession = session.fromPartition(‘persist:id’);

session.webRequest.onBeforeRequest(['*://*./*'], (details, cb) => {
         if (adBlockActiveForSession(details.webContentsId)){
                  // adblock operations
         }
}
```

This **works in the development and with production flag**. However, when I create a **release/executable, it doesn't work**. I noticed that, **in the release, details doesn't have “webContentsId”**, but it does in development.

Also I have check the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request) and it says that the webContentsId is an optional value in the onBeforeRequest callback.

why it works in development but not when I create a release? When can webContentsId be access in the parameter details and when it can’t?  There is some flag I should use when doing the release package? Should I consider this a bug? has someone experienced the same issue?

Thank you

*note: In order to insure that the webview has its webContent id, before loading an url I load an empty site, and after dom ready, I start to do the real url loadings.*

---

**Operating system:**

development in Ubuntu, Mac, release in Mac, Windows. Both releases have the same problem.

**Expected behavior**

onBeforeRequest should return the information of the webContent that has created the request. That information is inside details.webContentsId

**Actual behavior**

onBeforeRequest returns it when working in development version and with the production on, however, when doing a package to create a release onBeforeRequest doesn’t return the webContentsId of the webContent that did the request

Comment: This seems like a bug that got introduced in electron v3.0.0. I've opened a bug for it: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15329

Comment: I did open a bug in the past but they didn't consider it a bug. But I think is likely the way I phrased it. The problem is that I even posted this problem in their forums and nobody replied, so its something that was in the air for a lot of months now

Comment: I provided a minimal repro, which is the best way to get a bug looked at. I saw your bug  report, i think it was too vague to be actionable